# noSql joins, relational data move to noSQL store, and playOrm

Tags: nosql

We see TONS of posts on putting relational data into noSQL and needing to denormalize it.  Is this really because the tools don't exist?  playOrm has S-SQL which seems to scale just fine.  If you don't use partitions, it won't scale and you would simple be moving DBMS data into a noSQL store that still can't scale, but once you move to partitions, it scales just fine.

So my question is do we really have a tools problem? and we will see more and more tools like playOrm that CAN do joins and can deal with relational data in a noSQL store just like we dealt with relational data in a DBMS?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2):

In a traditional OldSQL databases you denormalize to improve read performance, 
by removing the need of joins, at the cost of more complex updates.
In an NoSQL database you might need to denormalize because of the lack of support of joins. 
Still it is good for read performance but do complicate updates, especially if the NoSQL 
database does not support transactions. To add support of joins in a tool on top of the database 
adds another layer which definitely will decrease performance, even more than if the underlying 
database would support joins.

If something scales well horizontally (almost linearly), performance can easily be achieved by 
adding more nodes. A join scales well horizontally only if the data is partitioned so that each join 
between two rows/posts can be executed locally in one single database node. This might be achieved 
for some predefined joins, but I argue that in general most NoSQL databases will have performance 
problems supporting complex ad hoc queries involving joins.

Take a look at a different alternative, our NewSQL database Starcounter do support join queries 
and provides great performance.

Comment: Actually a join across nodes with playOrm on 1,000,000 rows was timed out to be 60ms to return 100 rows so I tend to disagree with getting bad performance on joins in partitioned nosql case ;).  +1 for your thoughts though.  Also, playOrm will eventually use a lookahead join to get better performance.